# angular function called before two way binding complete

Tags: angularjs, binding, angular-ngmodel

In my custom angular directive I'm receiving a method as a parameter.
When the user changes some value in my directive I update the directive's ngmodel and execute the function.

Apparently there is a usecase where the function passed uses the ngmodel used by my directive. From some reason the model doesn't update when the function is called, but only later.

Is there any way to execute the method only once the ngmodel's two way binding has taken place?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the ngModel is undefined in your directive's update method.

```
function update(){
  if(ngModel !== undefined){
    passedInFunction();
  }
}
```

Comment: the issue is that the ngmodel is defined and set to an old value

Comment: well then you could add a watch to the ngmodel and check for a change. When it changes then call out to the passedInFunction.